# Why don't the sorted collections in .NET have matching interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, sorting, base-class-library

.NET has a bunch of [sorted collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z658b67%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However, only implementations were added, such as:

- [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`SortedSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, none of these implement a "matching" interface, they only implement `IList<T>`, `IDictionary<Tkey, TValue>` and `ISet<T>`.

In my opinion, the fact that a collection is sorted is something that you might want to communicate to your consumers without further specifying a specific implementation. Furthermore, I don't think that adding such interfaces would be complicated.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way, perhaps?

Comment: The answer to every "why was x designed so-and-so" is "because". Also, usually backwards compatibility and new insights.

Comment: @CodeCaster even so, I find that this contrasts with how .NET is otherwise designed. They offer an interface to pretty much every collection, and they have a very powerful hierarchy that always works out. Adding an `ISortedList<T>` to the bottom of that hierarchy seems so simple.

Comment: `SortedList<>` and `SortedDictionary<>` are from .NET 2.0 . The title of your post seems to imply that they are new in .NET 4.0

Comment: I do understand your reasoning, it's just pretty hard to get an authoritative answer here. Yes, there are users present who (used to) work on C# and .NET, but the "why"  may be unavailable to them. All answers you're going to get will be speculative at best, or contain reasoning that you may or may not agree with (in other words: opinion-based).

Comment: because they are just sorted. the sorting part is done inside methods such as adding or the constructor when creating it. then what would be the implementation of `ISortedList<T>`? just an empty interface?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I use empty interfaces a lot just to tell consumers what something is and how it behaves. Sorting is a behaviour, interfaces communicate behaviour.

Comment: the name of the class already says this is sorted. empty interface would not add any useful functionalities... btw im **not** trying to be negative here. this is just what i think...

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary It does indeed, but what if another implementation of sorted is offered later, implementing such empty interface. Suppose you have a public library with a class that wraps `SortedList`, and you expose that `SortedList` in your methods. Now, if you want to use the new implementation, *all* your (theoretically infinite) consumers need to switch to the new implementation, whereas with an interface, that problem would not exist.

Comment: These classes are not sealed.  So if you want to expose an ISortedList to clarify the programmatic interface then just add it.  It will be the smallest collection class you ever wrote.

Answer (score 3):

I will say that it is "because there is no way to convene how the `SortedXXX<>` is sorted". The `IComparer<>` interface isn't self-describing.

If I told you "this collection is sorted", would this information be important for you? Perhaps it is sorted by the SHA256 of its keys... It is still sorted, but is sorted by something that no human person would consider an "ordering"? The only guarantee given by this "sorted" would be that two runs of `GetEnumerable()` would return the items in the same ordering (so the `GetEnumerable()` would be "stable"). `HashSet<>` doesn't even guarantee it probably.

To give an example:

```
var ss1 = new SortedSet<string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

A "classical" `SortedSet<>`, ordered by the `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`. It is "sorted" to something a human will recognize.

```
var ss2 = new SortedSet<string>(Comparer<string>.Create((p, q) => p.GetHashCode().CompareTo(q.GetHashCode())));
```

A `SortedSet<>` ordered by the `GetHashCode()` of its elements. No human would "appreciate" it... But it is still sorted :-)

If you then proposed "then the interface could simply implement a `Comparator` getter to return which comparator is used" (ignoring that the comparators aren't self-describing), note that:

```
var cmp1 = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase; // instance of System.CultureAwareComparer
var cmp2 = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase; // instance of System.CultureAwareComparer

bool same = object.ReferenceEquals(cmp1, cmp2); // false
```

and then

```
var cmp3 = StringComparer.CurrentCulture; // instance of System.CultureAwareComparer
```

Woops... It is even difficult to distinguish between `StringComparer.CurrentCulture`/`StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`.

In the end my point is:

**if you knew a collection is sorted, what could you do with that information without knowing if its sorting is the one you need?**

Comment: I agree with everything you say, although I don't see how this is an argument against having interfaces. The implementation has the exact same "problem" and doesn't expose it in any way (I mean it's equally vague). Paraphrasing your answer, you are saying that "sorting is a behaviour that can be implemented in multiple ways". That sounds much like what interfaces are for, IMHO.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester An interface must give a complete information. My point is that simply saying "it is ordered" is a useless (because incomplete) information.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester The real question is: if you knew a collection is sorted, what could you do with that information without knowing if its sorting is the one you need?

Comment: the fact that after any operation, the list remains in a sorted state and I do not have to sort it myself and I can always reliably dump it as-is while knowing the result is sorted. I may be 100% wrong in thinking this is valuable information, but who defines what is valuable and what not?

Comment: *but who defines what is valuable and what not* Ah this is simple: some bigwig at Microsoft :-) Or if you are lucky some very good engineer :-)

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester For two out of three classes you can't sort it yourself. For `ISet<>` and `IDictionary<,>` it is absolutely impossible to reorder the items. The ordering is something that is handled internally by the implementation. For `IList<>` classes it is clearly possible to force an ordering.

Comment: There is `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @Magnus That interface is used for supporting secondary ordering (`.OrderBy(A).ThenBy(B)`, so to support the `ThenBy(B)`). While the information that the `IEnumerable` is ordered is in this way exported, and so it is a response to the question, it remains still a quite useless information (for the reason I gave in my response, the interface doesn't describe the ordering). Note that that the interface is still very useful (for the technical reson I gave in this comment, the `.ThenBy`)

Comment: Just saying it can be useful to know that a sequence is ordered. Not necessarily how it is ordered.

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of someone who can give you a concrete answer I offer up an opinion:

The fact that a collection is sorted is an *implementation detail*, and as such there is nothing of interest to put on a suggested interface such as `ISortedDictionary`.

Comment: I think the border between implementation and interface is not so sharp when it comes to sorted. Example: you expose an `IEnumerable<T>` and a consumer wants it to be sorted. The consumer will attempt to sort an already sorted collection, which AFAIK is at least an O(n) operation.

Comment: If you need to know whether a set has been sorted, that implies that you need to know how it was sorted. You could get your ISorted<T> and say, "great, it's sorted," when upstream the comparer used to sort was changed. If that change doesn't impact the consumer then the consumer doesn't really care about the sort method and therefore wouldn't need to know whether it was already sorted. There could be scenarios where all of those things do matter, but if that happened we could create our own classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interface for `SortedDictionary<T,T>` - it's `IDictionary<T,T>`.
Also, `SortedSet<T>` implements `ISet<T>`.

That illustrates a reason why there aren't "sorted" interfaces. The interface defines how you interact with the class, not its implementation. What a consumer of that class needs to know is that it behaves as a dictionary. It doesn't need to know that anything gets sorted. If it does need to know that then it shouldn't depend on the interface. It should depend on the class.